# How to make a spectrogram in R

Tags: r, code, spectrogram

I have a a wave file and I need to make a spectrogram in R. I also need to be able to look at a specific time of the whole recording in the spectrogram. Anybody knows how to?

Comment: Sorry, as far as I see the R documentation has multiple examples on how to create spectrograms, but is there something missing in your question that goes beyond the examples on the web?

Comment: For example https://hansenjohnson.org/post/spectrograms-in-r/

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend using seewave. Something like this should be good:

```
# install packages if needed
install(seewave, tuneR)

# activate packages
library(seewave)
library(tuneR)

# read the .wav file
wav_file <- readWave(file_path)

# plot spectrum for section 2-6 secs in wav file
spectro(wav_file, tlim=c(2,6))
```

You can see more on other potential parameters here:
https://rdrr.io/cran/seewave/man/spectro.html